# Convert Time Zone formatted datetime to local date time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

Can someone point out this `"20130913095509+1000"` datetime represent which  format in .NET.

I am able to parse this with following code

```
string test= "20130913095509+1000";
DateTime parseDt = DateTime.ParseExact(test,
                    "yyyyMMddhhmmsszzzz",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    

//For comparison 

string output= parseDt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmsszzzz"); 
//output= 20130913095509+10:00
```

What is difference between `"20130913095509+10:00"` and `"20130913095509+1000"` in terms of Format in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You'd be better to parse this as a `DateTimeOffset` rather than a `DateTime`.  That way, the local time zone of the machine you are working on does not affect parsing behavior, and you don't need to worry about the madness that is `DateTimeStyles` or `DateTimeKind`.  Since `DateTimeOffset` retains the offset you give it, it will survive the round trip from string to object back to string without changing.
- `zzzz` is not a valid format specifier according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  It may appear to be honored by some implementations, but what's probably happening is that `zzz` and `z` are being interpreted separately, with the latter being ignored.
- Unfortunately, there is not a format specifier that represents an offset with sign, hours, and minutes without a colon.  `zzz` is the closest, which includes a colon when formatting with `ToString`, but treats it as optional when parsing with `ParseExact`.  Thus you can use `zzz` in your format string, but you'll have to remove the `:` manually after a `ToString` call.

Putting this together:

```
string test = "20130913095509+0530";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(test, "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dto.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz").Remove(17,1);
Console.WriteLine(output);  //=>  20130913095509+0530
```

Note that the format you are using is close to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) "basic" format, however that would include the `T` separator between the date and time components.  If possible, you should consider inserting the `T` such that your data is ISO 8601 compliant.

```
string test = "20130913T095509+0530";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(test, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dto.ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz").Remove(18,1);
Console.WriteLine(output);  //=>  20130913T095509+0530
```